# Excel VBA logic: get range between two cells using loops

Tags: excel, vba

Forgive me, as this may be very simple. I am trying to create a VBA macro that quickly gets statistics from raw data and puts them in a table. The raw data comes in this format:

[image]

(They will not always be in groups of three)

How would I get the range for all of a category, and then use that same range for Columns B and C to get the statistics I need?

Comment: why wouldn't you copy the category down all the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code get you the row numbers of each category and assumes there is no break in content on column B, your question was to get the content of columns C:D by category, having these row values will enable you to code to get the content of C:D.

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim WkSht       As Worksheet
Dim StrCategory As String
Dim LngRow      As Long
Dim LngRowStart As Long

Set WkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData")
    'Take note of the category we are one
    StrCategory = WkSht.Range("A" & 2).Value

    'Take not of the row the category started on
    LngRowStart = 2

    'Look to the next row
    LngRow = 3

    'Loop through the data until column B has no value, signifying the end of the dataset
    Do Until WkSht.Range("B" & LngRow) = ""

        'Go to the next row until we are given a new category or make it to the end of the dataset
        Do Until (WkSht.Range("A" & LngRow) <> "") Or (WkSht.Range("B" & LngRow) = "")
            LngRow = LngRow + 1
        Loop

        'Talk in the immediate pane
        Debug.Print StrCategory & " is on rows " & LngRowStart & " to " & LngRow - 1

        'Get the next values
        StrCategory = WkSht.Range("A" & LngRow)
        LngRowStart = LngRow

        'Move on
        LngRow = LngRow + 1
    Loop
Set WkSht = Nothing

End Sub
```

Below is the input data I gave it: -

[image: Input]

Below is the output from the code: -

[image: Output]

Comment: This works but it's not updating the category name, so it prints out: A goes from 2 to 4.....A goes from 5 to 7...A goes from 8 to 10, etc

Comment: Hmm, and in the data you are working with it doesn't go `A`, `[blank]`, `[blank]`, `A` does it?

Comment: No, the data will always have a value

Comment: Sorry I mean column A, Category, in your sample data your testing with its not `A`, `[blank]`, `[blank]`, `A` is it? I've added pictures to my answer to show you what I see. You change `Debug.print` to `MsgBox` just in case its something odd in the immediate window.

Comment: Turns out I'm just dense (typo in my code). Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some `If` statements and pull this all into an array, but it seems more direct to just fill in the blanks

```
Sub FillColA()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B"))
    Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"

End Sub
```